# WSO2 API Mananager - startup failures when accessed during startup

Tags: wso2

Currently using API Manager 1.6, though we've seen this issue on 1.4 as well. The problem is that if you send any API requests to the gateway in the time between when it opens the port to listen and the server being fully ready, the server crashes with this error:
[PassThroughMessageProcessor-5] ERROR APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation

This is an issue because I have a health check that checks the gateway every 15 seconds, and will cause the server to crash if it hits it during startup.

Is this a known bug? Currently the only way I've found around it is to add in some iptables rules around the starting of the service, but it's not ideal.

Thanks.